# Grub: Attempt to read outside of disk

Tags: linux, boot, grub

error occurred in grub how to fix and the computer not booting
I tried some solutions does not work

[image: Error: can't read the h01 disk error]

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'.
Entering rescue mode...
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please tell us more about this computer and how the error came to be. Did the computer work recently? What are the PC’s specifications? Were components upgraded/changed lately? Anything else that may be of note?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not just update your OS, and haven't made any other changes, your SSD probably just failed.  I had a cheap Lite-ON (I believe) SSD fail one time, and after it failed, it suddenly looked like a 64MB SSD and not 128GB.  Reads past the end of device would return errors.  SSDs can do all sorts of crazy stuff when they kick the bucket.

However, make sure any of the below isn't true:

- Do you have any external drive connected, external NVMe or USB?  It might be thinking that is `hd0` for some reason.
- Did you just install Linux or update GRUB?  Something may have gone wrong there.
- Did you just install a new hard drive?  Your old drive might be `hd1` or other number now.  You can edit the GRUB boot options and change `hd0` to `hd1` if you think this would be the case.  See this: [https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ways-to-rescue-or-recover-grub-menu#:~:text=Method%201%20To%20Rescue%20Grub%201%20Type%20ls,the%20command%20with%20every%20option.%20...%20More%20items](https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ways-to-rescue-or-recover-grub-menu#:%7E:text=Method%201%20To%20Rescue%20Grub%201%20Type%20ls,the%20command%20with%20every%20option.%20...%20More%20items)

Comment: Thanks LawrenceC